# Passing by reference to an char array

Tags: c, pointers

This is my code.

```
int main(int  argc, char *argv[]) {
    int shmid;
    char *shmc;
    char *shmp;
    pid_t pid;


    shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 3 * sizeof(char), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);    

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        shmc = (char *) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
        shmc[0] = argv[1];  
        shmc[1] = argv[2]; 
        shmc[2] = argv[3]; 
        
        shmdt(shmc);  
    }else{
        wait(NULL);

        shmp =(char*) shmat(shmid,NULL, 0);

        char *arg_vec[]={"./test", &shmp[1], &shmp[2],NULL};
        execv("./test", arg_vec);
        shmdt(shmp);
        shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);    
    }
}
```

```
        char *arg_vec[]={"./test", &shmp[1], &shmp[2],NULL};
```

In this line, I was trying to pass 2, 3 to another c program. But it passes 23 and 3. I wonder why and how can I fix the problem. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This was already addressed in my answer to your previous question that you deleted: `&shmp[1]` is a pointer to a single character, not to a string.

Comment: Besides that: Deleting a question after you got answers is not how SO works.

Comment: if &shmp[1] is a pointer to a single character, then why it is passing 2 chars? Is there a way I can pass "2" only to the arg_vec[]?

Comment: In an array all elements are stored right after the other. You store 2 and 3 in adjacent elements and no space for a nul-terminator. When you use the address of such an element as a pointer to string (which `execv`does) all consecutive char`s will be read until a 0 is found.

Comment: And you are somehow lucky. The memory after `shmp[2]` does not even belong to your process. You might get much more garbage printed or just cause a crash.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: But is there a way I can fix this plz?

Comment: No, I deleted 'cause I didn't describe my last question very well.

Comment: The either edit the question (if only a minor change) otherwise ask a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `execv` expects an array of pointers to strings. What you provide matches the type but not the logic behind:

```
char *arg_vec[]={"./test", &shmp[1], &shmp[2],NULL};
```

The addresses you use to initialize the parameter array are only pointers to single `char`, no strings.

In `shmp` all elements only have 1 byte and they are located at consecutive memory addresses. There is no place for some terminating 0 byte that would make your array a valid string.

You need to provide and initialize more space:
(Assuming you can ensure that numbers are only 1 digit)

```c
shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 3 * sizeof(char[2]), 0666 | IPC_CREAT);

char (*shmc)[2] = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
sprintf(shmc[0], "%d", number[0]);
...
char (*shmp)[2] = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
printf("%s, %s\n",shmp[1], shmp[2]);
char *arg_vec[]={"./test", shmp[1], shmp[2], NULL};
```

I leave it for you to ensure proper lengths and adapt in case you need larger numbers.

Comment: Is it better to use 3 * sizeof(int) for larger numbers?

Comment: You are dealing with character arrays. Why would you want to use `sizeof(int)`?  Maybe take `3*sizeof(char[5])` or simpley `3*5` to hold 3 numbers up to 4 digits each.

Comment: because I want it to take any integer parameter.

Comment: No, you don't want to take integer parameters. What you want is strings! `execv` takes strings, nothing else. It is your job, to put any integer or whatever you like, into a string. That requires an array of sufficient size for each of the parameters.